# Reference current value of property before ON MATCH SET within neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

For the app I am building, users can rate each other after each phone call (similar to Whatsapp). For the algorithm I am implementing, User A's average rating should be updated such that it equals the average of all the other users' average ratings of User A. For example, if there are 3 users and both User B and User C have rated User A, then I want to calculate User A's average rating as follows:

```
((User B's average rating of User A) + (User C's average rating of User A)) / 2
```

This is my query:

```
MATCH (u1:User { userId: $userId })-[r1:PARTICIPANT]-(c:Chat { roomId: $roomId })-[r2:PARTICIPANT]-(u2:User)
WHERE (r1.participantDuration > 0) AND (r2.participantDuration > 0)
SET r1.rating = $rating
MERGE (u1)-[r3:REVIEW]->(u2)
ON CREATE SET
    r3.ratingCount = 1,
    r3.averageRating = $rating,
    u2.averageRating = ((u2.averageRating * u2.uniqueRatingCount) + $rating) / (u2.uniqueRatingCount + 1),
    u2.uniqueRatingCount = u2.uniqueRatingCount + 1
ON MATCH WITH r3.averageRating AS oldAverage, r3.ratingCount AS oldCount SET
    r3.averageRating = ((oldAverage * oldCount) + $rating) / (oldCount + 1),
    r3.ratingCount = oldCount + 1,
    u2.averageRating = u2.averageRating + ((r3.averageRating - oldAverage) / u2.uniqueRatingCount)
RETURN u2 { .averageRating }
```

I am having an issue with capturing the previous state of averageRating and ratingCount before `ON MATCH SET` gets executed. I think I am getting an error because neo4j does not allow a `WITH` clause after `ON MATCH`.

Also, is there a better way to approach this query that may be more performant and hopefully more readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the old values by just referencing them

```
MATCH (u1:User { userId: $userId })-[r1:PARTICIPANT]-(c:Chat { roomId: $roomId })-[r2:PARTICIPANT]-(u2:User)
WHERE (r1.participantDuration > 0) AND (r2.participantDuration > 0)
SET r1.rating = $rating
MERGE (u1)-[r3:REVIEW]->(u2)
ON CREATE SET
    r3.ratingCount = 1,
    r3.averageRating = $rating,
    u2.averageRating = ((u2.averageRating * u2.uniqueRatingCount) + $rating) / (u2.uniqueRatingCount + 1),
    u2.uniqueRatingCount = u2.uniqueRatingCount + 1
ON MATCH SET
    r3.averageRating = ((r3.averageRating *  r3.ratingCount) + $rating) / ( r3.ratingCount + 1),
    r3.ratingCount = oldCount + 1,
    u2.averageRating = u2.averageRating + ((r3.averageRating - r3.averageRating) / u2.uniqueRatingCount)
RETURN u2 { .averageRating }
```